# Conditional rendering to one button in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have array that I'm mapping over to create buttons for my navbar. However I want a button with a specific name (Profile) to show a dropdown when clicked.

Currently with the below code, no dropdown is showing when 'Profile' button is clicked. Or when I try with other code, the dropdown shows when other buttons are clicked that are not 'Profile'

This is the array I have.

```js
export const NavbarInfo= [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Home',
        link: '/',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Profile",
        link: "/profile",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "About",
        link: "/about",
    },
```

This is the condition rendering I have tried so far. I have also tried to used a ternary condition for the `onClick` e.g. `item.name === 'Profile' && showAccountsDropdown`

```
import { NavbarInfo } from '/NavbarInfo'

function Navbar() {
    // Hooks /////////////////////
    const [navShow, setNavShow] = useState(false)
    const [showAccountsDropdown, setShowAccountsDropdown] = useState(false)

    const handleDropdown = (item) => {
        (item.name === 'Profile'){
            setShowAccountsDropdown(!showAccountsDropdown)
        }
    }

    const handleNavSelect = () =>{
        setNavShow(!navShow)
    }

    return (
        <div className='navbarContainer '>
              
            {NavbarInfo.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <div className='navOptions flex justify-center items-center py-0'>
                                <NavLink key={item.id} to={item.link} id={item.id} className='flex flex-row-reverse'
                                 onClick={(item)=>{handleNavSelect();handleDropdown(item)}}>
                                    {showAccountsDropdown? <h1>More info</h1>: null }
                                    {item.name}
                                    <span className='mt-1 mx-1'>{item.icon}</span>
                                </NavLink>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```

I want to achieve something similar to this, but unsure how to go about it when rendering buttons using map.

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY4se.png)

Comment: This is not a "json file" - it is just an object. A json-file, as the name suggests, would be in a seperate file, ending with `.json`.

Comment: Please also show your imports, as there are none. Did you import the NavbarInfo?

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so I've made the changes above

Comment: What is the specific issue or problem you are asking for help with? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Taking a deeper look. Checking your code out in a sandbox.

Comment: You deleted post while I was trying to answer last night. In either case, the code in the post had several issues that I've tried to address.

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

1. The code uses the same single `showAccountsDropdown` state to control each item's "dropdown", `showAccountsDropdown` will be true or false for all items at the same time.

   ```
   const [showAccountsDropdown, setShowAccountsDropdown] = useState(false)

   ...

   {NavbarInfo.map((item) => {
     return (
       <div className="navOptions flex justify-center items-center py-0">
         <NavLink ... >
           {showAccountsDropdown ? <h1>More info</h1> : null}
           ...
         </NavLink>
       </div>
     );
   })}
   ```
2. The `NavLink` component's `onClick` handler is passing the click event through to the `handleDropdown` callback.

   ```
   const handleDropdown = (item) => { // <-- item is click event
     (item.name === "Profile") {   // <-- never true
       setShowAccountsDropdown(!showAccountsDropdown);
     }
   };

   ...

   {NavbarInfo.map((item) => {
     return (
       <div className="navOptions flex justify-center items-center py-0">
         <NavLink
           ...
           onClick={(item) => {    // <-- click event
             handleNavSelect();
             handleDropdown(item); // <-- click event passed through
           }}
         >
           ...
         </NavLink>
       </div>
     );
   })}
   ```
3. Could be copy/paste errors/typos, but there is an extra closing `div` tag in your example, and `handleDropdown` is missing the `if` statement.

## Solution

I suggest the following updates:

1. Use the `showAccountsDropdown` state to hold the active `item.name` value.
2. Update `handleDropdown` to toggle the `setShowAccountsDropdown` between null and `item.name`.
3. When mapping the nav items check that `setShowAccountsDropdown` equals the current `item.name` to conditionally render the "dropdown". Fix the click event issue.

Code:

```
function Navbar() {
  const [navShow, setNavShow] = useState(false);

  // Initially null, e.g. no active item
  const [showAccountsDropdown, setShowAccountsDropdown] = useState(null);

  const handleDropdown = (item) => {
    // If item.name is already in state, set back to null to deselect
    // otherwise set to new item.name
    setShowAccountsDropdown((show) => (show === item.name ? null : item.name));
  };

  const handleNavSelect = () => {
    setNavShow(show => !show);
  };

  return (
    <div className="navbarContainer ">
      {NavbarInfo.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div className="navOptions flex justify-center items-center py-0">
            <NavLink
              key={item.id}
              to={item.link}
              id={item.id}
              className="flex flex-row-reverse"
              onClick={() => {
                handleNavSelect();
                handleDropdown(item); // <-- pass current mapped item
              }}
            >
              {/* Check if current item is the "active" one */}
              {showAccountsDropdown === item.name ? <h1>More info</h1> : null}
              {item.name}
              <span className="mt-1 mx-1">{item.icon}</span>
            </NavLink>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit conditional-rendering-to-one-button-in-react]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state variable to track the currently selected/clicked item and then check if it matches with the current map item.

```
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
```

//remaining code

```
{NavbarInfo.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <div className='navOptions flex justify-center items-center py-0'>
                            <NavLink key={item.id} to={item.link} id={item.id} className='flex flex-row-reverse'
                             onClick={()=>{setSelected(item.name);handleNavSelect();handleDropdown(item)}}>
                                {showAccountsDropdown && selected === item.name? <h1>More info</h1>: null }
                                {item.name}
                                <span className='mt-1 mx-1'>{item.icon}</span>
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
```

PS: While using event listener on loop like onClick here, do not pass your loop item as the argument to the event listener.